# Any way to allow STDIN in python over ssh with heredocs?

Tags: python, bash, ssh, stdin

I have a bash script that takes in 3 parameters. I need to ssh into a remote terminal and execute a python script there using those parameters.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    ssh -t -t -c blowfish -XC someServer << EOF
      python -u pythonToExecute.py $1 $2 $3
    EOF
```

The python script takes these parameters, and based on certain combinations, might ask the user to specify an action (using raw_input)

The issue I'm having is that the python script hangs after any input is inserted (assuming an issue with STDIN).

The python script works perfectly if I call python within the ssh call, but then I can't use the bash arguments.

I CANNOT use Paramiko, fabric, or any other external modules/packages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just calling like below?

```
ssh someServer python -u pythonToExecute.py $1 $2 $3
```

What does "I can't use the bash arguments." means ?

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I was too tunneled into current methods.  Thanks Tsuneo!